# Getting information from a datagrid

Tags: c#, linq, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid filled with information from a local database. When I click on one of these options I want put that information into a variable and put the information into a textblock.

I have some code fro this however the 'selected' always returns a null.

Here is the code:

```
private void lbxManagerDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagerTBL selected = lbxManagerDisplay.SelectedItem as ManagerTBL;

    if (selected != null)
    {
        txtblock_ManagerName.Text = selected.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

And here is how I populated the datagrid

```
 var PopulateManagers = from m in db.ManagerTBLs
                   where m.ManagerName != null
                   orderby m.TeamName descending
                   select new
                   {
                       ID = m.Id,
                       Manager_Name = m.ManagerName,
                       Nationality = m.ManagerNationality,
                       Team = m.TeamName,
                       Trophies = m.TrophyCount,
                   };
lbxManagerDisplay.ItemsSource = PopulateManagers.ToList();
```

Just so everyone knows `lbxManagerDisplay` is a `DataGrid`

Comment: Question Updated

Comment: I don't see the structure of the `ManagerTBL` class so I changed my answer to select the entire entry `m` from the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't select objects of type `ManagerTBL` but you select anonymous objects from you data base with this line:

```
select new {
```

So it is not possible for the compiler to cast it in the `SelectionChanged` event.

Try and change the select statement to (I don't know the structure of the class `ManagerTBL` so I suggest to take the entire entry):

```
var PopulateManagers = from m in db.ManagerTBLs

           where m.ManagerName != null
           orderby m.TeamName descending
           select m;
```

You can also take only a piece of information, but if you want to cast it to a specific type you need to make a custom class to store this information

```
public class MTBL_DataContainer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Manager_Name { get; set; }
    public string Nationality  { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public int Trophies { get; set; }    
}


var PopulateManagers = from m in db.ManagerTBLs
               where m.ManagerName != null
               orderby m.TeamName descending
               select new MTBL_DataContainer
               {
                   ID = m.Id,
                   Manager_Name = m.ManagerName,
                   Nationality = m.ManagerNationality,
                   Team = m.TeamName,
                   Trophies = m.TrophyCount,
               };
lbxManagerDisplay.ItemsSource = PopulateManagers.ToList();
```

And in the end you can cast it like this:

```
private void lbxManagerDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MTBL_DataContainer selected = lbxManagerDisplay.SelectedItem as MTBL_DataContainer;

    if (selected != null)
    {
        txtblock_ManagerName.Text = selected.ID.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow take one peice of information from the query I have (i.e the ID) so that I can search for that?

Comment: of course you can take only a piece of information, but if you want to cast it to a specific type you need to make a custom class to store this information

Comment: Like a partial class?

Comment: no like an extra container, a partial class would still have all the other properties and fields as the `ManagerTBLs`